# Google Tag Manager Removing some {{Click Text}}

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track link clicks so i've set up a tag with the label as {{Click Text}}

However, if I have the following html, it returns "Hello World I dont want this text"

```html
<a href="http://example.com"> 
Hello World 
<span><p> I dont want this text </p></span>
</a>
```

How do I exclude "I dont want this text" from the result?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you have a trigger with type `Click-Just Links`. Then, to achieve only `Hello World` in your tag you need to do the following:

1) Create Variable:

Type: Custom Javascript

Code: `function () {return $({{Click Element}}).clone().children().remove().end().text();}`

Name: Click Text Without Children

2) In your trigger, you can use variable `{{Click Text Without Children}}` which will return only `Hello world` for you